# how to delete one to many associations in flutter firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, nosql, one-to-many

I am developing a flutter application and I am using firebase database as a database service.

Now my since my app is a task management app my database have three main collections:

+roles

+tasks

+users

every role is a document with a unique id  and name

every task is a document with a unique id a name and a role id

now in the app the user is able to add roles in the database I just add a new role document to the roles collection

but I am stuck when it comes to deleting a role.

Obviously roles and tasks are a one-to-many association since one role can be associated with none or more than one task but one task can at most have only one role.

So when I want to delete a role I have to delete the associated tasks with it as well and only deleting the role will then generate a null error in the task since it doesn't find the specified role in the database anymore.

Now I really don't find any hint in the flutter firebase documentation on how to delete more than one document based on a selected criteria.

for example deleting one document based on its document id is straightforward

```
Future<void> deleteRole(Role role) {
final reference = databaseInstance.document('/roles/${role.id}');
return reference.delete();
}
```

if i want to read a task based on certain criteria like someId i will just write something like this

```
Stream<List<Task>> readTasksStream({@required String someId}) {
    Stream<QuerySnapshot> snapshots = databaseInstance
    .collection('tasks')
    .where('someId', isEqualTo: someId)
    .snapshots();

//now deserialize the data to objects and return it 

return snapshots.map((snapshot) => snapshot.documents
    .map((snapshot) => Task.fromMap(snapshot.data))
    .toList());
}
```

but how can i actually do the same for deleting a task based on someId in this case the roleId.
Something like this:

```
deleteTasksAssociatedWithARole({@required String roleId}) {
    Stream<QuerySnapshot> snapshots = databaseInstance
    .collection('tasks')
    .where('someId', isEqualTo: someId)
    .snapshots();

    //now I want to delete the selected document from the querysnapshot
    // but how ???????? 
}
```

I hope you get what I want to do here.
Any suggestion or help is very welcomed. 
Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete all documents matches by the query, you loop over the stream for `forEach` and then delete them each in turn.

Something like:

```
snapshots.forEach((snapshot) => snapshot.documents
    .forEach((snapshot) => Task.fromMap(snapshot.data))
    .toList());
}
snapshots.forEach((document) => document.reference.delete());
```

I find it easiest to figure out how to do this by following the types in the reference documentation, in this case from the [`snapshots` property](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/snapshots.html).

Answer (score 0):

[Frank van Puffelen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209103/frank-van-puffelen)

thank you so much it worked now.
so the final code is like this:

```
Future<void> deleteTasksAssociatedWithARole({@required Role role}) {
   Stream<QuerySnapshot> snapshots = databaseInstance
    .collection('tasks')
    .where('roleId', isEqualTo: role.id)
    .snapshots();

   return snapshots.forEach((snapshot) =>
    snapshot.documents.forEach((document) => document.reference.delete()));
}
```

so instead of deserializing the document snapshots to objects you loop through them with a forEach loop extract its reference to delete the document.